# typescript errors in .spec files in visual studio web application

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, karma-jasmine, typescript2.0

I have set up visual studio web app using angular 4 and typescript 2.4.2.
But i'm still getting some errors related to typescript from the karma and jasmine files.

I tried changing the es5 to es6 but still the error persists.I have read a lot of solutions but none of them are working.

**Screenshot of the errors**

[image]

Below is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "angularapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.35",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.16",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.85",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "bootstrap",
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
            // add path to @types
            "node_modules/@types"
         ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is what i did

1. npm upgrade
2. npm install --save-dev "@types/jasmine"
3. then in app.component.spec.ts
   **import { } from 'jasmine';**

clean and build it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Just to point out - it's dangerous to run upgrade as-is in production apps.